# Connection error to my server from multiple ISP's - mobile data works fine

Tags: domain-name-system, debian

I have a mailcow server that's been running with no problems for a couple of months (on debian 11 - mailcow.ruonline.com.au), but seemingly out of the blue, lots of my clients have started calling me in the last week or so, complaining that they can't connect to the server when using their wifi networks. The clients use a random array of Australian ISP's.

When I ask the client to switch to a mobile data hotspot, they can connect fine, but this is obviously a nuisance for them, and quite dodgy.

I've tried helping the clients do a DNS cache flush on a few individual computers, but that doesn't help, and even when the clients try to connect directly to the IP address of the server, it's the same. Works fine on mobile data, but connection errors on wifi (connection refused, timeout errors, etc).

It feels like some kind of conspiracy, like a bunch of ISP's have blocked my server thinking it's malware (it's not, it's legit transactional emails only - not listed on any MX blacklists).

Does anyone have any ideas about this?

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.